# Template template parameter with a concept - why does GCC reject it?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts, template-templates

I'm writing a generic struct that is templated on another template. I want the inner template to only accept types that match a concept.

```
template<template<std::regular> typename T> struct example{};
template<template<std::regular> typename T> using example_t = example<T>;
```

The above code compiles fine on MSVC and Clang, but GCC gives an error ([View on compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/WYsEocWGr)):

```
<source>:4:72: error: constraint mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<template<class> class requires  regular< <template-parameter-2-1> > T> struct example'
    4 | template<template<std::regular> typename T> using example_t = example<T>;
      |                                                                        ^
<source>:4:72: note:   expected 'template<class> class requires  regular< <template-parameter-2-1> > T' but got 'template<class> class requires  regular< <template-parameter-2-1> > T'
```

Which compiler is correct here?

Comment: This should be a bug of gcc, I think. Its error message is even contradictory, that is, `note:   expected 'X', but got 'X'`.

Comment: Agreed, submitted [111485](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=111485).

Comment: Thank you. A bug in GCC was my suspicion as well.